# how to display totals from two different queries at bottom of same column in SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible (without c# code) to pull in a second TOTAL row from a different query, and have it appear under another total from another query, in the same SSRS report?  How to do with the following example?

example:

```
create table LeadTracker
(property_name varchar(30), lead_id int);


insert into LeadTracker values
('Property1', 18709),
('Property1', 18323),
('Property1', 19547),
('Property2', 18709),
('Property2', 19015),
('Property2', 18323),
('Property2', 19547),
('Property3', 19015),
('Property3', 18323),
('Property3', 19547),
('Property4', 19015),
('Property4', 19547);
```

--first query shows how many leads were sent to each property and totals it at the bottom: 12 leads total.

```
select 
property_name,
count(distinct lead_id)
from leadtracker
group by property_name;

select
count(distinct lead_id)
from LeadTracker;
```

--second query shows that only a total of 4 were *unique* leads. I need this 'unique lead' total to appear beneath the total leads.

```
select
count(distinct lead_id)
from LeadTracker;
```

---in SSRS I need the results combined into a single column, like this

```
select 
property_name,
count(distinct lead_id) as leads_sent
from leadtracker
group by property_name
union all
Select property_name = 'Total', leads_sent = 12;
```

PLUS the result of this column underneath it

```
 Select count(distinct lead_id) 'TOTAL UNIQUE leads only'
 from LeadTracker;
```

Comment: @t_m That is not true, as you can use the `LOOKUP` feature in `SSRS`, I always just found this way easier.

Comment: @DanielE .. Thanks for the correction. That you can use data from another dataset within one table object.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Unique as int = (Select count(distinct lead_id) from LeadTracker);

select property_name
    ,count(distinct lead_id) as leads_sent
    ,@Unique [Unique]
from leadtracker
group by property_name
```

Add a row under your total row and use `=first(Fields!Unique.Value)` in the report, otherwise ignore it.

If you need to bring it under another dataset, you can use the `LOOKUP` as

```
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

This `<<Expr>>` would look something like:

```
 =Lookup(Fields!property_name.Value, Fields!property_name.Value, Fields!Unique.Value, "Unique_DataSet_Name")
```

[MSDN Page for LOOKUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`? Then you can do this all in one query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(property_name)=0
    THEN property_name
    ELSE 'Total Unique'
  END AS leads_sent
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
FROM leadtracker
GROUP BY property_name WITH ROLLUP
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/504db/10).